# LDAP bulk user profile update

Tags: ldap, openldap, opendj

I have a OpenDJ server with 300 users under People OU. I want to update a new attribute in all user profiles. Created that new attribute in this OpenDJ. Is there any script to update this new attribute with its Value in all user accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Generate an ldif file that adds this attribute to the 300 users, then give this file to `ldapmodify`.

Comment: Thanks. Worked this :-)

Comment: Please accept as the best answer if that worked for you.